# Reordering names in a column within a list of data frames according to a specific sequence of names

Tags: r

I am trying to reorder dataframes in a list according to a specific sequence of names.
These are results of a complex ANOVA, which I tried to replicate using the Cars93 dataset. I need the results of the final ANOVA sorted according to a specific sequence of names of Manufacturer.
Eg. I would like all the dataframes in the list to be order according to a specific order of names: "Eagle", "Acura", "Buick", "Chevy", "Cadillac", "Dodge", "Chrysler", "Hyundai", "Ford" ...and so on.

anova_carmanuf_letters is the target/final list of data frames resulting from this analysis. In this list, I need to reorder the results according to the names in the first column "Manufacturers". This needs to be in a specific sequence. Ideally this should be in an order I prefer, eg. "Eagle", "Acura", "Buick" ...and so on. But even an alphabetical ordering would be great.

```
#Copy-paste and run this code in RStudio to end up with the anova_carmanuf_letters list with dataframes.
#libraries for ANOVA, including multiple comparisons, linear models and least square means.
library(FSA)
library(car)
library(multcomp)
library(lsmeans)
library(multcompView)

#Using the Cars93 dataset, and keeping specific columns
carmanuf <- subset.data.frame(Cars93, select = c("Manufacturer", "Min.Price", "Price", "Max.Price", "MPG.city", "MPG.highway", "Cylinders", "EngineSize", "Horsepower", "RPM"))

#Names of columns with data to run ANOVA on
datanames <- names(carmanuf)[2:10]

#Using lapply to run least squares means, tukey post-hoc, etc on all parameters
model_carmanuf <- lapply(datanames, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(i ~ Manufacturer, list(i = as.name(x))), data = carmanuf)})

ls_carmanuf <- lapply(model_carmanuf, function(model_carmanuf) 
lsmeans(model_carmanuf, pairwise ~ Manufacturer, adjust = "tukey"))

anova_carmanuf_letters <- lapply(ls_carmanuf, function(ls_carmanuf) cld(ls_carmanuf[[1]], alpha = .05, Letters = letters, adjust = "tukey"))

#I am able to reorder one data frame at a time using the following code, and changing the [[1]] to [[2]] and so on. But it would be great if I could use lapply or a for loop to do it for all the data frames contained within this list, as my actual analysis has ~90 such data frames in a list.
anova_carmanuf_letters[[1]]$Manufacturer <- factor(anova_carmanuf_letters[[1]]$Manufacturer, levels = c("Suzuki", "Geo", "Saturn", "Hyundai", "Subaru", "Plymouth", "Ford", "Dodge", "Eagle", "Honda", "Pontiac", "Toyota", "Mercury", "Nissan", "Mitsubishi", "Chevrolet", "Mazda",  "Volkswagen", "Oldsmobile", "Chrylser", "Saab", "Buick",  "Acura", "Chrysler", "Volvo", "BMW", "Audi", "Lexus", "Lincoln", "Cadillac", "Mercedes-Benz", "Infiniti"))
```

Comment: First, please include ALL `library` lines so we understand what methods are being read (see `r` tag). Few of these are not in R's base libraries. Second, if that object is the list of dataframes, what is `anova_carmanuf_letters$Manufacturer`? Shouldn't it be `anova_carmanuf_letters$Eagle`, `anova_carmanuf_letters$Acura`, etc.? Do you have a nested list?

Comment: Manufacturer is the column name, and Eagle, Acura etc are names in that column. This works for a single dataframe. Obviously it doesn't work in this case, which is where I need help.

Comment: Im not sure you read the code. If you do, you will see where anova_carmanuf_letters is generated. Its towards the end of this analysis. If you just copy and paste the whole code in RStudio, you will get the final anova_carmanuf_letters list with dataframes. Cars93 is a dataset included in all R  and RStudio installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since output is a list of data frames, specifically list of `"summary_emm"` class objects which extends `data.frame`, you can run straightforward data frame operations:

```
str(anova_carmanuf_letters[[1]])
# Classes ‘summary_emm’ and 'data.frame':   32 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ Manufacturer: Factor w/ 32 levels "Suzuki","Geo",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ lsmean      : num  7.3 9.1 9.2 9.32 11.37 ...
# $ SE          : num  5.93 4.19 5.93 2.96 3.42 ...
# $ df          : num  61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 ...
# $ lower.CL    : num  -12.2807 -4.7457 -10.3807 -0.4654 0.0617 ...
# $ upper.CL    : num  26.9 22.9 28.8 19.1 22.7 ...
# $ .group      : chr  " abcd  " " ab    " " abcde " " a     " ...
# - attr(*, "estName")= chr "lsmean"
# - attr(*, "clNames")= chr  "lower.CL" "upper.CL"
# - attr(*, "pri.vars")= chr "Manufacturer"
# - attr(*, "adjust")= chr "tukey"
# - attr(*, "side")= num 0
# - attr(*, "delta")= num 0
# - attr(*, "type")= chr "link"
# - attr(*, "mesg")= chr  "Confidence level used: 0.95" "Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 32 estimates" "P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 32 estimates" "significance level used: alpha = 0.05"
```

Specifically, consider `lapply` to adjust the *Manufacturer* factor levels.

```
myvars <- c("Suzuki", "Geo", "Saturn", "Hyundai", "Subaru", "Plymouth", "Ford",
            "Dodge", "Eagle", "Honda", "Pontiac", "Toyota", "Mercury", "Nissan", 
            "Mitsubishi", "Chevrolet", "Mazda",  "Volkswagen", "Oldsmobile", 
            "Chrylser", "Saab", "Buick",  "Acura", "Chrysler", "Volvo", "BMW", 
            "Audi", "Lexus", "Lincoln", "Cadillac", "Mercedes-Benz", "Infiniti")

anova_carmanuf_letters <- lapply(anova_carmanuf_letters, function(df) 
            within(df, Manufacturer <- factor(Manufacturer, levels=myvars))
)
```

However, do be aware that no visible ordering occurs with above command, only the levels within factor column. You can `order` afterwards on new levels even combining the two `lapply` calls:

```
anova_carmanuf_letters <- lapply(anova_carmanuf_letters, function(df) 
            df[order(df$Manufacturer),])


anova_carmanuf_letters[[1]]

# Manufacturer   lsmean       SE df     lower.CL upper.CL  .group
# 29        Suzuki  7.30000 5.927581 61 -12.28072477 26.88072  abcd  
# 12           Geo  9.10000 4.191433 61  -4.74566327 22.94566  ab    
# 27        Saturn  9.20000 5.927581 61 -10.38072477 28.78072  abcde 
# 14       Hyundai  9.32500 2.963790 61  -0.46536239 19.11536  a     
# 28        Subaru 11.36667 3.422290 61   0.06172995 22.67160  ab    
# 24      Plymouth 11.40000 5.927581 61  -8.18072477 30.98072  abcde 
# 11          Ford 12.43750 2.095716 61   5.51466837 19.36033  a     
# 9          Dodge 12.51667 2.419925 61   4.52286925 20.51046  ab    
# 10         Eagle 12.70000 4.191433 61  -1.14566327 26.54566  abcd  
# 13         Honda 13.06667 3.422290 61   1.76172995 24.37160  abc   
# 25       Pontiac 13.28000 2.650895 61   4.52323367 22.03677  ab    
# 30        Toyota 14.02500 2.963790 61   4.23463761 23.81536  abc   
# 20       Mercury 14.10000 4.191433 61   0.25433673 27.94566  abcde 
# 22        Nissan 14.85000 2.963790 61   5.05963761 24.64036  abc   
# 21    Mitsubishi 15.05000 4.191433 61   1.20433673 28.89566  abcde 
# 6      Chevrolet 16.08750 2.095716 61   9.16466837 23.01033  abc   
# 18         Mazda 16.34000 2.650895 61   7.58323367 25.09677  abcd  
# 31    Volkswagen 16.45000 2.963790 61   6.65963761 26.24036  abcde 
# 23    Oldsmobile 16.55000 2.963790 61   6.75963761 26.34036  abcde 
# 7       Chrylser 18.40000 5.927581 61  -1.18072477 37.98072  abcdef
# 26          Saab 20.30000 5.927581 61   0.71927523 39.88072  abcdef
# 4          Buick 20.75000 2.963790 61  10.95963761 30.54036  abcdef
# 1          Acura 21.05000 4.191433 61   7.20433673 34.89566  abcdef
# 8       Chrysler 22.00000 4.191433 61   8.15433673 35.84566  abcdef
# 32         Volvo 23.30000 4.191433 61   9.45433673 37.14566  abcdef
# 3            BMW 23.70000 5.927581 61   4.11927523 43.28072  abcdef
# 2           Audi 28.35000 4.191433 61  14.50433673 42.19566  abcdef
# 16         Lexus 31.10000 4.191433 61  17.25433673 44.94566   bcdef
# 17       Lincoln 33.85000 4.191433 61  20.00433673 47.69566    cdef
# 5       Cadillac 35.25000 4.191433 61  21.40433673 49.09566     def
# 19 Mercedes-Benz 36.40000 4.191433 61  22.55433673 50.24566      ef
# 15      Infiniti 45.40000 5.927581 61  25.81927523 64.98072       f
```

To keep needed columns and rename to corresponding original column name use `Map` for ekementwise looping through all 9 items of *datanames* and 9 data frames:

```
new_anova_carmanuf_letters <- Map(function(df, nm) 
       setNames(df[c("Manufacturer", ".group")], 
                c("Manufacturer", nm)), 
       df = anova_carmanuf_letters, nm = datanames)
```

Comment: RStudio is just an interface. What is the R error you receive? Please re-attempt in empty R environment.

Comment: For the future, if I have to replicate this problem in a minimal fashion to ask another question, can you recommend which code I can use? Eg. 1) I want to figure out how to delete the "lsmeans", "SE", "df"... columns from all the dataframes to keep only Manufacturer and group, and 2) rename the "group" to the respective "Min.Price, "Price"...  etc names.

Comment: The updated solution also works absolutely perfectly!